# To tag svn project during ROS release steps more easily

Tags: ros, svn, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When releasing from our `svn` as a development repository, we first create `tag` on `svn` repo and then run `bloom` (if there's a way where this step is not needed then this question loses its necessity. I appreciate if you could share that!).

Is there a way to automate this tagging for `svn` ? Tagging itself can be done by a single command like:

```
svn copy https://%TRUNK_PACAKGE% https://%PATH_TAG_PACAKGE%-1.0.1 -m "Releasing 1.0.1"
```

But I think of `catkin_prepare_release` that tags for `git` project. Is it bad/inappropriate to add `svn` support to `catkin_prepare_release`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80101/to-tag-svn-project-during-ros-release-steps-more-easily/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-09-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you actually tried to use "catkin_prepare_release"? It already supports svn and does the tagging of the repo for you.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1